# perf_buffer__new() is not working in linux 6.1. upto linux 6.0 samples/bpf user program is working fine

Tags: ebpf, xdp-bpf

I am working on user space application for xdp program  which uses perf_buffer__new() to get the packet data. Existing samples/bpf program which prints MAC header is working fine upto linux 6.0. from linux 6.1 it is not working . Am i missing something here.

I have tried linux different versions upto linux 6.0 xdp_sample_pkts application is working fine. From linux 6.1 it is not working. providing working/Non-working log.

Working log:

root@akb:/home/akb/SRC/net/net-next/samples/bpf# uname -a
Linux akb 6.0.0-rc2+ #153 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Nov 8 16:52:50 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@akb:/home/akb/SRC/net/net-next/samples/bpf# ./xdp_sample_pkts -S enp0s8
Pkt len: 60    bytes. Ethernet hdr: ff ff ff ff ff ff 30 42 40 c9 39 6c 08 06
Pkt len: 60    bytes. Ethernet hdr: ff ff ff ff ff ff 30 42 40 c9 39 6c 08 06

Non-working log:

root@akb:/home/akb/SRC/net/linux-net-next/samples/bpf# uname -a
Linux akb 6.1.0-rc1+ #16 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Nov  4 11:25:53 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@akb:/home/akb/SRC/net/inux-net-next/samples/bpf# ./xdp_sample_pkts -S enp0s8

Application does not print any data here.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What leads you to think this is an issue with `perf_buffer__new` and not something else in the sample BPF program?

Comment: since same sample program working in versions 6.0 and below , not working in 6.1 version. only other call in application is perf_buffer__poll() with respect to perf_buffer calls.thanks for the response.

Comment: I'd suggest to either bisect the commit that broke this or to report to the BPF mailing list.